# Select base template per site

Tags: wagtail

I am building a setup that will contain a main site and a number of microsites. Each microsite is going to have a separate branding but use the same page types.

Given Wagtail already has a `Site` object which links to an appropriate `Page` tree, is there also built in functionality to configure the template loaders to choose an appropriate `base.html` or will I have to write a custom template loader?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wagtail doesn't have any built-in functionality for this, as it doesn't make any assumptions about how your templates are put together. However, you could probably implement this yourself fairly easily using the [`wagtail.contrib.settings`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/reference/contrib/settings.html) module, which provides the ability to attach custom properties to individual sites. For example, you could define a TemplateSettings model with a `base_template` field - your templates can then check this setting and dynamically extend the appropriate template, using something like:

```
{% load wagtailsettings_tags %}
{% get_settings %}
{% extends settings.my_app.TemplateSettings.base_template %}
```

Answer (score 7):

I extended [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35413238/4391298) to provide an override of the `{% extends ... %}` tag to use a `template_dir` parameter.

myapp.models:

```
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting

@register_setting
class SiteSettings(BaseSetting):
    """Site settings for each microsite."""

    # Database fields
    template_dir = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                    help_text="Directory for base template.")

    # Configuration
    panels = ()
```

myapp.templatetags.local:

```
from django import template
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.template.loader_tags import ExtendsNode
from django.template.exceptions import TemplateSyntaxError


register = template.Library()


class SiteExtendsNode(ExtendsNode):
    """
    An extends node that takes a site.
    """

    def find_template(self, template_name, context):

        try:
            template_dir = \
                context['settings']['cms']['SiteSettings'].template_dir
        except KeyError:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "'settings' not in template context. "
                "Did you forget the context_processor?"
            )

        return super().find_template('%s/%s' % (template_dir, template_name),
                                     context)


@register.tag
def siteextends(parser, token):
    """
    Inherit a parent template using the appropriate site.
    """

    bits = token.split_contents()

    if len(bits) != 2:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("'%s' takes one argument" % bits[0])

    parent_name = parser.compile_filter(bits[1])
    nodelist = parser.parse()

    if nodelist.get_nodes_by_type(ExtendsNode):
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(
            "'%s' cannot appear more than once in the same template" % bits[0])

    return SiteExtendsNode(nodelist, parent_name)
```

myproject.settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            ...
            'builtins': ['myapp.templatetags.local'],
        },
    },
]
```